# Function definition notation

Tags: functions, notation

When I've a function $\text{f}$ and it can be depended on $x$ (where $x$ will be a real number) or other real number(s) (constant(s)), can I define the function as follows?:

$$\exists\space\text{f}\left(x\right)\mapsto\left\{\text{f}\left(x\right)\in\mathbb{R}:\forall\space x\right\}$$

Or is there a more common or good notation?

Comment: @Leonhard So: $$\text{f}:\text{X}\mapsto\mathbb{R}\space\forall\space x\in\space\text{X}$$?

Comment: The other way, often clearer, is to define it using words, not symbols.

Comment: @Leonhard This is not good notation; it should be $\to$, not $\mapsto$, plus $X$ is not currently defined (domain is mentioned to be $\mathbb{R}$), nor should we have to specify that this holds for all $x$ in the domain (that is already implied by this notational format).

Answer (score 4):

The "signature" of the function (a programming term, I believe, which might not be standard amongst mathematicians; it basically means "domain and codomain" in this context) is written $f: S \to \mathbb{R}$, whatever $S$ is. Note that this *does not* involve the input to the function, so (for instance) it's really quite weird to write something like $f: x \to \mathbb{R} \ (x \in \mathbb{R})$; in this instance, $x$ is the *input* to $f$ and hence shouldn't appear in the function's signature. Notice also that $\mapsto$ tells us what happens to a particular input to the function, while $\to$ tells us what the domain and codomain of the function are.

For example, we may write the factorial function in the following ways (by no means an exhaustive list!):

- $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $n \mapsto n!$
- $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $x \mapsto x!$
- $f: \{ 1, 2, 3, \dots \} \to \{ x: x \in \mathbb{R} \}$ given by sending $i$ to $i \times (i-1) \times \dots \times 2 \times 1$.
- $G: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $r \mapsto r!$
- $n \mapsto n!$ (this expression, without specifying the "signature" of the function, will suffice if the domain and codomain are clear from context)

Comment: So, for my application I can write: $$\text{f}:x\to\mathbb{R}\space\space\space\space\space x\in\mathbb{R}$$?

Comment: You're looking for $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, unless I've misunderstood your example. Can you be more explicit about what $f$ is, so I can check if I understand you correctly?

Comment: (By the way, I explicitly said in my answer that $f: x \to \mathbb{R} \ (x \in \mathbb{R})$ would be a strange expression.)

Comment: The function $\text{f}$ can be depend on $x$ (that will be a real number) so then I can write $\text{f}\left(x\right)$, but when it does not it is just a constant (a real number). So how can write that correctly?

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what $f$ is? It seems to be a function which takes an optional argument; is that correct?

Comment: I want to say that the function $\text{f}$ is real for every value of $x$ and when it does not depend on $x$ it is just equal to a real number.

Comment: You could write $f:X\times Y \to \mathbb{R}$ where $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} g(x) : y=0 \\ c : y\neq 0, \end{cases}$$ where $y\in \{0,1\}$ is a variable that determines whether $x$ is relevant, and $g:X\to \mathbb{R}$. We don't have functions that have optional arguments in math.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer : $$f:\begin{Bmatrix} X\rightarrow \Bbb R \\ x\mapsto f(x) \end{Bmatrix}$$ Where $\operatorname{dom}\text{f}=X\subset \Bbb R$

Answer (score 0):

You could write $f:X\times Y \to \mathbb{R}$ where $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} g(x) : y=0 \\ c : y\neq 0, \end{cases}$$ where $y\in \{0,1\}$ is a variable that determines whether $x$ is relevant, and $g:X\to \mathbb{R}$. We don't have functions that have optional arguments in math.

Comment: I'm assuming the downvote on this answer is because the question is worded poorly. This is the only answer that addresses what the OP meant. You can see that by reading the other comments on other answers.

Answer (score -1):

If the function $f$ depends only from one real variable $x$  and has a real value, than you can write:
$$
f:X\to \mathbb{R} \qquad X \subset \mathbb{R}
$$
remember that the function is well defined only if **for all** $x \in X$ we have a value $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Why the capital letters? And, when the function $\text{f}$ depend on a real number and not on $x$ does that notation is valid in that case?

Comment: So can I also write: $$\text{f}:x\mapsto\mathbb{R}\space\space\space x\in\mathbb{R}$$?

Comment: @Poilys The Capital $X$ denotes a set of elements $x$ and note that $\rightarrow$ is different from $\mapsto$.

Comment: @Poilys: Capital letters because $X$ is the **domain** of the function, that is a set , and, in this case it is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. ( I've edit a typo in my answer).